# How to iterate over node var in Primefaces tree to set icons in CSS class from DB

Tags: css, primefaces, icons

I am using PF v. 5.3.5 and JSF v. 2.2.8.

```
<p:tree value="#{userFiltersBean.objectsTreeModel}" var="node" hideRootNode="true" styleClass="filtersTree">
                <p:treeNode icon="">
```

My CSS class is below:

```
.ui-treenode-icon{
    background: url("#{node.leafIcon}") no-repeat top !important;
}
```

I see the same icon in each treeNode that it is not desired. This icon is for the final treeNode in the tree.
However, I want to iterate trough them that each treeNode has his own icon.

**NOTE** The size of tree is different on each environment and it is created dynamically.
How can I do this, please?

Please, see current PF version [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC36P.png).
The desired Icefaces version is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZmiO.png).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED without css**

I solved by inserting a h:graphicImage inside treeNode without facet. it now as I needed and how it was done in the previous version.

```
<p:tree value="#{userFiltersBean.objectsTreeModel}" var="node" hideRootNode="true" styleClass="filtersTree"
                            selectionMode="checkbox">
    <p:treeNode>
        <h:graphicImage value="#{node.leafIcon}" />
        <h:outputText value="#{node.text}" />
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Api-Documentation (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/tree/basic.xhtml -> Documentation Tab) it says you could do it like this:

```
<p: tree value="#{bean.root}" var="doc">
    <p:treeNode type="mp3" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-video">
         <h:outputText value="#{doc.name}" />
    </p:treeNode>
    <p:treeNode type="document" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-image-document">
         <h:outputText value="#{doc.name}" />
    </p:treeNode>
</p:Tree>
```

So in the backing Bean you have to give the Node a name, which will  be the p:treeNode type. So as far as I understand

```
TreeNode mp3 = new TreeNode("mp3", "some music");
```

would do the linking for

```
<p:treeNode type="mp3" ... />
```

Let me know if it helped.

Cheers
kyhu :)

Answer (score 0):

Having different values for each element with one CSS class is not possible. You would have to create a class for each icon, like so:

```
my-treenode-icon-1 {
    background: url("/resources/img/treenode/icon-1.jpg") no-repeat top !important;
}
my-treenode-icon-2 {
    background: url("/resources/img/treenode/icon-2.jpg") no-repeat top !important;
}
```

and then in iteration use icon name instead of path (if you have a path in database you can slice last part of it and take only the image name which will be class name).

```
<p:tree value="#{userFiltersBean.objectsTreeModel}" var="node" hideRootNode="true" styleClass="filtersTree">
                <p:treeNode icon="my-treenode-#{node.iconName}">
```

Comment: This is a good idea but my depth of tree is dynamic (different on each environment). So, I need to create these CSS classes dynamically. Do you have any idea how to do it, please?